# How to generate warning if a structure is declared without "__attribute__(align(8))"

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-construction

I want the compiler to generate warning for me if structure declared without `__attribute__(align(8))` .

For example, if a structure is declared like this:

```
struct my_float {
        float number;
}  __attribute__((aligned(8)));
```

It will not generate any warning. But if I declare another struct like this:

```
struct my_float {
        float number;
};
```

the compiler will generate a warning for me.

My working enveronment is linux/GCC.

Comment: You want to generate a warning if **any** structure is declared without the attribute?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yes...

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. To my knowledge, there is no way to force an attribute on every `struct` definition. Unfortunately, there is also not a command-line switch to set this (unlike packing, for example).  I'm not sure why you would need such a thing, however.

Comment: Why this is Important for me?
1) I have two program running in my machine, one is 32bit and another is 64bit and they have some shared structure.

Now these shared structures are needed to align as per 64bit config.

Comment: What are you talking about? A 64 bit machine doesn't mean that everything needs to be 8 byte aligned. In fact, usually most types (including `int` and `float`) have exactly the same size and alignment. Types which are larger (e.g. `long int` on *nix) may also need different alignment, but the size difference is a bigger problem.

Comment: @delnan FromFollowing link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/transition/transition.html

what I want to do written in section:"Files stored on disk"
I want to : make sure that the size and alignment of data structures are the same in 32 and 64bit versions;

Comment: @iDebD_gh Ah, so OS X increases the alignment of `long long` without increasing the size. I still think you shouldn't blindly increase the alignment of everything, only of types which have different alignment in 32/64 bit. You could even have an automated test to ensure that the relevant structures have the right size and alignment.

Comment: Link you posted about files on disk has nothing to do with the data alignment. Aligment has no meaning when saving to disk. You should be more concerned about padding, but you are not saving raw structs to disk, are you? Section also says: *"Finally, never underestimate the convenience of a generic exchange format"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can automatically check this an ALL your structure, but you still can check your alignment manually with something like:

```
// x % 16 <=> x & (16-1)  (avoid using modulo operator)
#define MODULO_16_MASK 0xFU
ASSERT_COMPILE((sizeof(my_float) & MODULO_16_MASK) == 0);
```

This should trigger a warning at compiling if your structure is not aligned.

Answer (score 0):

From experience, it is not possible to do.
This attribute specifies a minimum alignment (in bytes) for variables of the specified type.

```
struct S { short f[3]; } __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
typedef int more_aligned_int __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
```

force the compiler that each variable whose type is struct S or more_aligned_int is allocated and aligned at least on a 8-byte boundary.